# How to work with minibarjs Custom Scrollbar pure javascript?

Tags: javascript

```js
new MiniBar('#myContent',{

    // or progress
    barType: "default",

    // min size
    minBarSize: 10,

    // always shows scrollbars
    alwaysShowBars: true,

    // enables horizontal/vertical scrollbars
    scrollX: true,
    scrollY: true,

    // shows nav buttons
    navButtons: false,

    // scroll amount in pixels
    scrollAmount: 10,
    
    // MutationObserver API
    mutationObserver: {
      attributes: false,
      childList: true,
      subtree: true
    },

    // default classes
    classes: {
      container: "mb-container",
      content: "mb-content",
      track: "mb-track",
      bar: "mb-bar",
      visible: "mb-visible",
      progress: "mb-progress",
      hover: "mb-hover",
      scrolling: "mb-scrolling",
      textarea: "mb-textarea",
      wrapper: "mb-wrapper",
      nav: "mb-nav",
      btn: "mb-button",
      btns: "mb-buttons",
      increase: "mb-increase",
      decrease: "mb-decrease",
      item: "mb-item",
      itemVisible: "mb-item-visible",
      itemPartial: "mb-item-partial",
      itemHidden: "mb-item-hidden"
    }

    });
```

```css
 .conatiner{
 height:600px;
 
}

 .mb-track-y {
            height: 105px;
            width: 1px;
            /*height: 30%;*/
        }

 .mb-bar{
            -webkit-transition-property: height, width;
            transition-property: height, width;
            -webkit-transition-duration: 150ms;
            transition-duration: 150ms;
            -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
            transition-timing-function: linear;
        }

 .mb-track {
            background-color: #0066A7;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }

 .mb-track-y .mb-bar {
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            min-height: 10px;
            /*height: 20px!important;*/
        }

.mb-track-y .mb-bar {
            width: 5px;
            left: -2px;
        }
     .mb-bar {
            /*background-color: #4C9689;*/
            background-color: #29B351;
        }
     .mb-bar {
            z-index: 10;
            -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
        }

     .content
        {
            overflow: hidden;
            width: 100%;
            height: calc(100% - 12px);
        }


        
.container, .container-wide {
  margin: 20px;
 
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #4D394B;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
}

.content {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 72px);
}

.main-title {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #4C9689;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.content {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 72px);
}

.mb-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.container .mb-track-x {
    width: 50%;
}
.container .mb-track {
    background-color: #2E222D;
}
 .container .mb-track {
    background-color: #2E222D;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.mb-track-x {
    left: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
    width: calc(100% - 10px);
    height: 10px;
    opacity: 0;
}
.mb-track {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 250ms;
    transition: opacity 250ms;
}
.mb-bar, .mb-button, .mb-buttons, .mb-track {
    position: absolute;
}
.mb-bar, .mb-track {
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
}

.mb-track-y {
    right: 5px;
    top: 5px;
    height: calc(100% - 10px);
    width: 10px;
    opacity: 0;
}


.mb-track-y {
    height: 47%;
}

 .container .mb-bar, .container-wide .mb-bar {
    -webkit-transition-property: height, width;
    transition-property: height, width;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 150ms;
    transition-duration: 150ms;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
}

.mb-track-y .mb-bar {
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 10px;
    height: 20px;
}
.mb-bar {
    background-color: #4C9689;
}
.mb-bar {
    z-index: 10;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.mb-content {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/minibarjs@0.4.2/dist/minibar.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/minibarjs@latest/dist/minibar.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>HTML Tutorial</title>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h3 class="main-title">Default</h3>
    <div class="content" >
        <div class="inner" id="myContent">
            <div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

I am creating a custom scrollbar using minibar js.

https://preview.npmjs.com/package/minibarjs/v/0.3.3

new MiniBar('#myContent');
They have said the above line to initiliase the minibar.

It works when included outside a function

But I want to inistialise it within a function during onclick.
How to initialize the minibar js during onclick?

How to update the minibar during onclick to check for whether div is scrollable?

```js
function show_scroll(){
        new MiniBar('#myContent');
}

MiniBarOptions = {
    // or progress
    barType: "default",

    // min size
    minBarSize: 10,

    // always shows scrollbars
    alwaysShowBars: false,

    // enables horizontal/vertical scrollbars
    scrollX: true,
    scrollY: true,

    // shows nav buttons
    navButtons: false,

    // scroll amount in pixels
    scrollAmount: 10,
    
    // MutationObserver API
    mutationObserver: {
      attributes: false,
      childList: true,
      subtree: true
    },

    // default classes
    classes: {
      container: "mb-container",
      content: "mb-content",
      track: "mb-track",
      bar: "mb-bar",
      visible: "mb-visible",
      progress: "mb-progress",
      hover: "mb-hover",
      scrolling: "mb-scrolling",
      textarea: "mb-textarea",
      wrapper: "mb-wrapper",
      nav: "mb-nav",
      btn: "mb-button",
      btns: "mb-buttons",
      increase: "mb-increase",
      decrease: "mb-decrease",
      item: "mb-item",
      itemVisible: "mb-item-visible",
      itemPartial: "mb-item-partial",
      itemHidden: "mb-item-hidden"
    }

    };
```

Comment: Can you please reproduce this one on any of the env. like codesandbox, jsfiddle etc so that debugging the issue would be easier?

Comment: https://www.cssscript.com/demo/stylish-custom-scrollbar-pure-javascript-minibar/